# How to align monthly time series next to weekly time series in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

My goal is to combine two time series (weekly in 1st column and monthly in 2nd column and the date format of the weekly time series).

I have a weekly time series with values from 2004-01-04 up to 2018-06-24.

I also have a monthly time series with values from 2004-01-01 up to 2018-06-01. (It always takes the first day of the month as -01)

For the monthly time series, I want to fill up the NA with the same value for every week in the same month.

I have tried the na.locf function in R:

`na.locf(merge(monthly, foo=zoo(NA, order.by=seq(start(monthly), end(monthly), "week")))[, 1])`

However, it does not quiet work out right.

In the end it should look something like this picture:

[image: Output Goal]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the melt function? This might help you out in the right direction.
(pressure is included in the default 'datasets'-package)

```
library(reshape2)

data <- head(pressure)

head(data)
melt(data, variable = "pressure")

    > head(data)
  temperature pressure
1           0   0.0002
2          20   0.0012
3          40   0.0060
4          60   0.0300
5          80   0.0900
6         100   0.2700

> melt(data, variable = "pressure")
      pressure   value
1  temperature 0.0e+00
2  temperature 2.0e+01
3  temperature 4.0e+01
4  temperature 6.0e+01
5  temperature 8.0e+01
6  temperature 1.0e+02
7     pressure 2.0e-04
8     pressure 1.2e-03
9     pressure 6.0e-03
10    pressure 3.0e-02
11    pressure 9.0e-02
12    pressure 2.7e-01
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! but my problem lies in extending the month time series with the weekly dates of my other time series and filling up the empty weekly entries of that month with the same monthly data points.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean but maybe it helps:

```
d<-data.frame(rep(c(3,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,NA),7),seq(as.Date("1999-01-01",tz = "GMT","%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2000-05-01",tz = "GMT","%Y-%m-%d"), by="1 week"))
colnames(d)<-c("data","Date")
time<-d$Date
a<-aggregate(d,by=list(substr(d$Date,1,7)),FUN=function(x) max(x,na.rm=TRUE))
colnames(a)<-c("Date","Data","xyz")
d$Date<-substr(d$Date,1,7)
t<-merge(a[-3],d[-1],by = "Date")
t$Date<-time
```